# Index container sample component

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin

I would like to implement a feed component that has multiple of:-

- an icon
- a label

The component could be backed by an IndexedContainer.

It would be helpful if the sample showed how to update the feed component when a new item is saved / or inputted the data source.

Comment: Usually you just do a insert into your `IndexedContainer`and this then triggers a refresh of the Table or Treeview or whatever component you use to display the data

Comment: Thanks Andre, I am actually trying to implement the component that uses the container and thought there was sample around that.

Comment: Trying to use the Grid component but the line / row height is always 37px regardless of the CSS I apply. I have followed the instructions in the Book of Vaadin but als nothing has helped thus far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need any lazy loading, you could get some inspiration from a still-to-be-published add-on that I've put together: https://github.com/Legioth/Listing/blob/master/listing/src/main/java/org/vaadin/listing/Listing.java

If you want to use the class as it stands, you might also be interested in this usage example: https://github.com/Legioth/Listing/blob/master/listing-demo/src/main/java/org/vaadin/listing/demo/Demo.java#L37

If you need lazy loading, I'd suggest trying to get `Table` or `Grid` to work according to your requirements.

Comment: Thanks Leif, I am going to try the Grid component for this and have used the Tabsheet component in the other instance. Your components have given me ideas on how to make my own better.